# How to combine 2d circle graph (with point which is rounded) into helix 3d graph (motion of particle along circle in the world line)

Tags: graphics3d, manipulate

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{Circle[], {Red, PointSize@.05, Point@{Cos[x], Sin[x]}}}],
 {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

and

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t/4}, {t, 0, 2 π a}], {a, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: `Circle[]` is not compatible with `ParametricPlot3D[]`. You can use `ParametricPlot3D[]` to plot a circle, however.

Answer (score 4):

Is this, what you are trying to get:

```
    Manipulate[
 Show[{
   ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t/4}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
   ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotStyle -> Gray],
   Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.03], Gray, Point[{Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}], Red,
      Point[{Cos[a], Sin[a], a/4}], Dashed, 
     Line[{{Cos[a], Sin[a], 0}, {Cos[a], Sin[a], a/4}}]}]
   }],
 {{a, 0.1}, 0, 6}]
```

yielding the following:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Please don't use JPG for non-photographic images! :)

Comment: @ Andreas Rejbrand Why not?

Comment: JPG is designed to be used with photographs, and it uses lossy compression that causes very disturbing artefacts in non-photographic images that contain a lot of solid-colour regions, text, curves, etc. I tried to explain this [here](https://english.rejbrand.se/rejbrand/msword.asp#graphics), and there is also an XKCD for this: Google "XKCD PNG vs JPG". (Although, I must admit that I have almost never seen a JPG with as *little* artefacts as your image.)

Comment: @ Andreas Rejbrand Look, I always post jpg files here using the screenshots and it never makes problems.

Comment: No, indeed, you use so little compression that it is barely visible. But in almost all other cases where people save screenshots and diagrams as JPG, the artefacts are very visible. (Still, resaving your image as PNG reduces the file size by almost 50%.)

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand  OK, thank you, I will have it in mind.

Answer (score 4):

```
 Manipulate[Show[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t/4}, {t, 0, 2 π a}, 
      MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {{ 2 π a - 1/10000 }}, 
      MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
    ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], π a/2}, {t, 0, 2 π }, {r, 0, 1}, 
      PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
      MeshFunctions -> {#5 &}, Mesh -> {{1 - 1/10000}}, 
      MeshStyle -> Red,
      BoundaryStyle -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
    PlotRange -> {0, 2 Pi}], {a, 1, 4}]
```

[image]